# Paginate mapped records in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have the following,

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Pagination from "rc-pagination";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import axios from "axios";

import "rc-pagination/assets/index.css";
import AuthService from "../Auth/AuthService";
const Auth = new AuthService();

class JournalIndex extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      journals: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/journals")
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ journals: res.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  delete(id) {
    let config = {
      headers: { Authorization: "bearer " + Auth.getToken() }
    };

    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this journal!",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true
    }).then(willDelete => {
      if (willDelete) {
        axios.delete("/api/journals/" + id, config).then(result => {
          this.props.history.push("/journals");
        });
        swal("Poof! Your journal has been deleted!", {
          icon: "success"
        });
      } else {
        swal("Your journal is safe!");
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className='p-12 text-gray-800'>
          <section className='text-center mb-12'>
            <h1 className='title'>Journals</h1>
            <p className='text-sm'>
              Here you'll find my journals, writings about everything from
              watches, repairs to dealing
            </p>
          </section>

          <section className='max-w-3xl m-auto'>
            {this.state.journals.map(journal => (
              <article className='pb-4' key={journal._id}>
                <Link
                  className='title dynamic-title'
                  to={`/journals/${journal._id}`}
                >
                  {journal.title}
                </Link>

                <div className='text-sm mt-2 mb-4'>
                  <Moment
                    format='Do MMMM YYYY'
                    date={new Date(journal.createdAt)}
                  />
                </div>

                {Auth.loggedIn() && (
                  <div className='mt-8 mx-auto text-center w-full'>
                    <hr />
                    <div className='my-4'>
                      <Link
                        to={`/dashboard/journals/${journal._id}/edit`}
                        className='btn btn-edit'
                      >
                        Edit
                      </Link>
                      <span className='text-gray-200 mx-4'>|</span>
                      <button
                        onClick={this.delete.bind(this, journal._id)}
                        className='btn btn-delete'
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
                <hr />
              </article>
            ))}

            <Pagination
              showTotal={range => `${this.state.journals.length} items`}
              total={`${this.state.journals.length}`}
            />
          </section>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default JournalIndex;
```

I am using the `rc-pagination` package but I'm looking to paginate all records in the mapped array so it only shows 10 items per page.

I've looked over the docs but I'm not too sure how to go about implementing it.

Or if anyone can point me to a pagination package and provide an example that would be great as am am looking to pagination on a few pages.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

`rc-pagination` has a [defaultPageSize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-pagination) prop that you can define as 10 or whatever else you want as a page size.

Comment: I've added that but it doesn't actually do anything, it still shows all records.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of this package/component.  It does not manage the data you're actually displaying for you, it's simply a configurable pagination menu so you don't have to build one yourself. If you want a component that's going to display an entire list.. you'd need to find another one based on the kind of data you're rendering, what you want to do with it and how you want it to look.  Maybe a table? [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) will handle pagination for you. Of course, you could manage the page props yourself. It's not too tricky.

Comment: I'm not using function components also react-table seems like massive overkill when your only going to be using on little part of the package.

Comment: Then I'd recommend just managing the current page, page size and data you're displaying in your state and passing them to the pagination menu as props. Use the size/current page to calculate start/end points for your array, then map over the sub-section dynamically based on that information.